# XSLT Example to replace some elements in XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML with ZIP and Territory Codes. I need a transformed XML with changed territory codes for some ZIP codes. In the sample XML below, I would like the code for ZIP 29000 changed from 0098 to 1298, and no change for ZIP 29455.

Can someone please provide me with some sample XSLT codes for this? Can we also pass the ZIP/Code pair to the XSLT program thru a text or XL file for which the updates are needed.

Thank you very much!

Input:

```
<root>
  <Territory id="p1">
    <Code>0098</Code>
    <ZIP>29000</ZIP>
  </Territory>
  <Territory id="p2">
    <Code>0052</Code>
    <ZIP>29455</ZIP>
  </Territory>
</root>

Required Output:
<root>
  <Territory id="p1">
    <Code>1298</Code>   // updated code here
    <ZIP>29000</ZIP>
  </Territory>
  <Territory id="p2">
    <Code>0052</Code>   // no change here
    <ZIP>29455</ZIP>
  </Territory>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a simple template to match and replace the targeted `Code` element with one that has the updated `Code` value:

```
<xsl:template match="Code[.='0098']">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:text>1298</xsl:text>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

To the XSLT identity transform,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Code[.='0098']">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:text>1298</xsl:text>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and run against your input XML to get the following output XML,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <Territory id="p1">
      <Code>1298</Code>
      <ZIP>29000</ZIP>
  </Territory>
  <Territory id="p2">
      <Code>0052</Code>
      <ZIP>29455</ZIP>
  </Territory>
</root>
```

as requested.